# .Net Webservice Data Type

Tags: .net, web-services, soap

I have created a SOAP Java Web Service and a Java WebService Client to invoke the Webservice.  The parameters are String and Double for the WebService.    When I invoke the webservice with java WebService client with a String and Double parameter,  I am getting the required response fromt the Web Service.  But when I invoke the same Web Service from .Net Web Service Client with a String value and 1.0 value,

```
ordConf[0].slNo = "1234"; <br/>
ordConf[0].qty = (Double)1.0; <br/><br/>
```

this WebService is unable to understand the Double value and throws NullPointerException for the double value.

How do I ensure that Double value is passed from .Net WebService Client to Java WebService. My wsdl complexType snippet is

```
xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="slno" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"  
xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="qty" nillable="true" type="xsd:double"
```

Here is the client code snippet.  
        WebReference.InterWareHouseService IwConf = new WebReference.InterWareHouseService(); 
        WebReference.IwOutboundOrder[] ordConf;
        WebReference.Response[] ordRespConf;

```
    ordConf = new WebReference.IwOutboundOrder[1];<br/><br/>

    ordConf[0] = new WebReference.IwOutboundOrder();<br/>
    ordConf[0].custOrderNo = "13337097";<br/>
    ordConf[0].itemNo = "DS-SFP-FC8G-SW";<br/>
    ordConf[0].slNo = "1234";<br/>
    ordConf[0].qty = 1.0;<br/>
    ordConf[0].weight = 0.5;<br/>
    ordRespConf = IwConf.confirmShipment(ordConf);<br/>
```

Comment: What kind of .NET web service client are you using? Did you use "Add Service Reference"? Can you show the code you use to call the service?

Comment: Appended the code to the above question

Answer (score 0):

Try using the value type `double` instead of the reference type `Double` in your java code.

Comment: Thanks Jonny. I changed the datatype to double in the Web Service.  Now it is not throwing NullPointerException but the value I am getting in the Web Service is 0.0. If I change the QTY value from double to String in the WebService then I am getting the values into the Web Service but ideally I want to receive only double into the Web Service. Any help?

Comment: There is likely a `qtySpecified` boolean available to check.  The other choice is have your C# class' `qty` property be of type `double?`.

Comment: Thanks Jonny.  Initially I dinn't understand qtySpecified availability check.   Later I downloaded a tool named Wizdl to test the Java WS.  In that tool they had a config qtySpecified boolean value.  When I set that value to true, the data was passing from .net to Java

Comment: Groovy.  I prefer [SOAP UI](soapui.org), but any tool that works works.